# How to create an output file (re)writed?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been trying to solve my script but I really would appreciate some help.
I have 2 input files.

The first one is a multi-fasta file with headers like this:

```
'>AH008024.2 Angelica acutiloba internal transcribed spacers 1 and 2, partial sequence'
'>AJ969149.1 Carthamus tinctorius partial ITS2'
....
```

(the quotes are just to let the > sign visible, otherwise it is not showed...)

The second one is a primer validation file which looks like this:

```
AB280738.1,UniplantR,49,68,forward,CCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC,20,71.4,,,56.5 - 69.8
AB280739.1,UniplantR,49,68,forward,CCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC,20,71.4,,,56.5 - 69.8
AB280740.1,UniplantR,49,68,forward,CCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC,20,71.4,,,56.5 - 69.8
...
```

I want to write a "rewrited" version of the second file, changing the accession number "AB280738.1" for the species names from the fasta file, generating a tab delimited output like this:

```
AB280738.1      Glycyrrhiza uralensis ITS1, 5.8S rRNA and ITS2     UniplantR 49 68 forward CCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC 20 71.4   56.5 - 69.8

AB280739.1      Glycyrrhiza glabra ITS1, 5.8S rRNA and ITS2      UniplantR 49 68 forward CCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC 20 71.4   56.5 - 69.8     
...
```

The final output must have the same number of lines that the second input file, the primers file, which in this case is 420 lines, but my current output is writing 292140 lines, it is doing the matching, but it is not writing properly.

I've been working on this code that I'm showing to you.
I see that the "matching" part of my script is working, but I think that I am not doing the right "push" step. Besides this, something is making my nested loops recursive, because there's multiple lines from the same match.
To know that it is working, the output must have the same number of lines that the second input, the primers input.
The second "print" tells me hou many times the pattern matched, and it is giving me 540 instead of 420.

I would like to upload my input files and my current output if someone would like to try with it, but I couldn't find where upload files..

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use diagnostics;
   use warnings;
   use strict;

   print "multifasta:\t";
   my $arq1 = <STDIN>;
   open (MYFILE, $arq1);
   my @file = <MYFILE>;
   close (MYFILE);
   print "file to rename:\t";
   my $arq2 = <STDIN>;
   open (MYFILE2, $arq2);
   my @file2 = <MYFILE2>;
   close (MYFILE2);
   my @new_file=();
   my $count = ();
   open (NEW_FILE, '>>plant_names_primer_bind_renamed.txt');
   foreach my $line2 (@file2) { 
           my @fields = split (/,/, $line2);
           my $accession2 = shift(@fields);
                   foreach my $line (@file) {
                           if ($line =~ /^>/) {    
                           my $rev = reverse $line;
                           chop ($rev);
                           my $header = reverse $rev;
                           my @header = split (/ /, $header);
                           my $accession = shift (@header);
                                 if ($accession =~ /$accession2/)        {       
                   $count++;
                   print "$accession2 match $accession\t@header\t@fields\n\n";
                   print "$count\n";
                   push (@new_file, ("$accession2\t@header\t@fields"));
                   print NEW_FILE @new_file;
           }      
        }       
      }       
   }
```

Comment: You could try upload test files to [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: My files uploaded:
input 1: https://ufile.io/k0zx0r3o
input 2: https://ufile.io/szweuy8g
expected/generated output: https://ufile.io/y8yyrk7g
my current script: https://ufile.io/s14x346o

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I read the multi fasta file headers into a hash before I start processing the primer validation file. In this way I avoid a double `for` loop:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
{
    my $fasta_data = read_fasta_file();
    print "file to rename:\t";
    chomp (my $fn = <STDIN>);
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $save_fn = 'plant_names_primer_bind_renamed.txt';
    open ( my $save_fh, '>', $save_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$save_fn': $!";
    my $count = 0;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my @data = split /,/, $line;
        if (@data) {
            my $key = $data[0];
            my $def = $fasta_data->{$key};
            if (defined $def) {
                #say ++$count;
                say $save_fh join "\t", $key, $def, @data[1..$#data];
            }
        }
    }
    close $save_fh;
    close $fh;
}  


sub read_fasta_file {
    print "multifasta:\t";
    chomp(my $fn = <STDIN>);
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my %data;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($key, $value ) = $line =~ /^>(\S+)\s+(.*)$/;
        $data{$key} = $value if defined $value;
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked, but it didn't write the output lines properly, I think it is because we are trying to write nested arrays, dont you think? so maybe it is messing the inner components of each array... Your script wrote 418 lines, nice, it fixed the loop, but it wrote all mixed, look: AB456050UniplantRoncirus49rifoli68a geneforwardTCCCGHYTGAYYTGRGGTCDC 26S20RNA, c71.4ete and partial sequ56.5 - 69.8men_voucher: THS:77968. I uploaded my files, if you would like to help me, its right after my question. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok great. *" look: AB456050UniplantRoncirus..."* : I downloaded your files `input1_only_its.fasta` and `input2_plant_names_primer_bind_sorted.txt` but I cannot find any reference in those files to "*Roncirus*" so I cannot reproduce the output you give

Comment: Note also: your files was DOS (windows type line endings) format so I had to convert to UNIX line endings before I could use my script, see [man fromdos](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/fromdos.1.html)

Comment: About the "Roncirus" I didn't find any refernce with this name in any of the 2 inputs, weird... and about the files, its something about the uploader, because I'm working on unix system.

Comment: I didnt because I took them directly from my server, where Im working, so I didnt think about converting, the windows did only the uploading in the website, should I do something different? could you just wc the files to me to check if it is the same?

Comment: I could email them to you? If its ok

Comment: sure! Just an extra detail, besides the "=-420" lines, another checking feature would be each output line have 3 fields, like using the cut -f "\t", 1 for accession, 2 for species name and 3 for primer details.

Comment: sorry I could not find your email address in your profile, if you send an email to me I will reply with the files, thank you!